# To-Do list application : Text is only added after clicking add button twice

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-constraintlayout

I'm currently making a to-do application, and I've made a plus button - on click, it asks the user for text and displays that on the screen. I must be missing something obvious, but my textview only displays after I click the button twice. The first time, it asks for input and I click Done. Nothing shows up. Then, I click the button again and instantly the textview pops up.

```
public void additem(View view){ 
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ConstraintLayout mainmenulayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainConstraint);
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        TextView itemtoaddtxv = new TextView(this);

    // Asking the user for input
        final AlertDialog.Builder inputAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        inputAlert.setMessage("Enter task");
        final EditText userInput = new EditText(this);
        inputAlert.setView(userInput);
        inputAlert.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                m_text = userInput.getText().toString();
            }
        });
        inputAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = inputAlert.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        itemtoaddtxv.setText("test");
    //

        itemtoaddtxv.setId((int)21); // I HAVE TO CHANGE THIS TO BE DYNAMIC AND INCREMENT ID EVERYTIME I ADD ITEM
        itemtoaddtxv.setWidth(366);
        itemtoaddtxv.setTextSize(20);
        mainmenulayout.addView(itemtoaddtxv, 0);

        set.clone(mainmenulayout);
        TextView titletxv = findViewById(R.id.menutitletext);    
set.connect(itemtoaddtxv.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,titletxv.getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,28);
        set.connect(itemtoaddtxv.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,mainmenulayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,12);

        set.applyTo(mainmenulayout);
        itemtoaddtxv.setText(m_text);
    }
```

I just want to click the button, enter text, click done and have it display. I've tried troubleshooting this for a couple of hours now and I can't figure it out. I'd appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in the Positive `onClick` you are setting the value. However, that is all you are doing. You need to move the code that actually adds it to the view. Like below:

```
    inputAlert.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                m_text = userInput.getText().toString();
                itemtoaddtxv.setText(m_text);
        itemtoaddtxv.setId((int)21);
        itemtoaddtxv.setWidth(366);
        itemtoaddtxv.setTextSize(20);
        mainmenulayout.addView(itemtoaddtxv, 0);

        set.clone(mainmenulayout);
        TextView titletxv = findViewById(R.id.menutitletext); set.connect(itemtoaddtxv.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,titletxv.getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,28);
        set.connect(itemtoaddtxv.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,mainmenulayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,12);

        set.applyTo(mainmenulayout);
        itemtoaddtxv.setText(m_text)
            }
        });
```

Comment: Worked for me! I had to make itemtoaddtxv a final variable too. Thank you!